# Is it possible to sort/group images create dates in a csv based on whether the following picture time is within 2 minutes of the previous?

Tags: r, image, grouping

[The image has the before spreadsheet with the dark background and the white spreadsheet is what I need as an end product to group the images into subjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoXIJ.png)I’m working with camera trap images that I want to have sorted into events, or the times when one individual is being detected in front of the camera. My csv currently has columns with the image ID, the size of the image, and the createdate or time stamp. I want to have any picture occurring within two minutes of the previous to be grouped together as an assumption of that being the same individual animal so it will only be identified once. In the csv each image ID would need to be present in a single cell going horizontal across the spreadsheet with each row representing an event.
I thought there may be a way to do this using the package lubridate, but I have not found anything that has pushed me in the right direction.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It could be easy to add a new column in with the Group number.
Sort the images by date and put first one Group = 1

then

if ( date [row]-date[row-1] > 2 min ) group[row]= groupe[row-1]+1

Later you can convert that values to numbers and use them to rename the images or whatever you want.

Comment: I see what you are going for with the first half of the code, but I'm not sure about the second portion. Also when i ran the first half inserting my objects they were not recognized. Could you take a look at my data picture and see if you can clarify by seeing it?